# Check for browser updates periodically

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm developing a WP Plugin which detects the current version of your browser and then I want to check (I don't know how) for the current browser last version and compare them in order to show a update your browser bar.

So, I wanto to know if there is a check fro updates way?

Thanks,

(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked here: http://www.browser-update.org/